# Subscheme associated to a coherent sheaf of finite length

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be a smooth surface. Let $F$ be a torsion free sheaf of rank $2$ on $X$, then we have an exact sequence $0 \to F \to F^{**} \to S \to 0$, where $S$ is a coherent sheaf of finite length, say $d$. The support of $S$ is a finite set say, $x_1, x_2, ...x_k$ such that $d= \sum \text{length}_{\mathcal{O}_{x_i}}S_{x_i}$.

Question: Can we canonically  associate a zero dimensional subscheme of length $d$ supported on $x_1, x_2, ...x_k$ ?

Comment: What does "canonically" mean?

Comment: By canonical, I meant the subscheme determined by $S$ uniquely.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $X=\mathbb{P}^2_\mathbb{C}$, and fix a point $x\in X$. Then take $F=M\oplus M$ where $M$ is the ideal sheaf of $x$. Thus, $S=\mathbb{C}_x\oplus \mathbb{C}_x$ where $\mathbb{C}_x$ is the skyscraper sheaf at $x$. Now, a subscheme of length 2 supported at $x$ is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^2)$ and determined by its tangent line. Clearly there is no canonical choice.